# Analytic refinement of generalized cohomology theories

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, cohomology, algebraic-k-theory, stable-homotopy

Recently, U.Bunke and others developed in a number of papers (such as [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.3188), [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.0247) or [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.6663)) an approach to smooth extensions of cohomology theories based on stable homotopy theory. In this approach a differentiable refinement of a cohomology theory is a sheaf from the category of smooth manifolds $\mathbf{Mfd}$ to the category of spectra. Of course proving that in this way one gets a cohomology theory satisfying an analogue of the Eileneberg-Steenrod axioms.

My naive question is the following: can one make a similar construction for the category of complex manifolds (with holomorphic maps) and obtain some kind of analytic refinement of cohomology theories?

Comment: This would be neatly captured by what Urs Schreiber calls _cohesive_ higher topos theory. Indeed his Habilitation is called "Differential cohomology in a cohesive $\infty$-topos" https://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/differential+cohomology+in+a+cohesive+topos, but perhaps a more specific pertinent reference is https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.3188, which, together with the material at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/complex+analytic+%E2%88%9E-groupoid, should allow a differential _holomorphic_ cohomology theory.

Comment: Yes.  Essentially it suffices to observe that complex manifolds look like a polydisk locally, so homotopy-invariant sheaves are once again equivalent to spaces.  The rest of the construction proceeds in the same way.  For example, using holomorphic differential forms instead of smooth forms one recovers holomorphic Deligne cohomology.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov If you would expand your comment to an answer I'll able to vote and accept it.